# Internet keeps dropping

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, wifi-configuration

My internet keeps on dropping intermittently to my home network in Windows 10 OS system but no problem with ethernet cable at all. If I connect to other network it does not happen. Surprisingly, other  laptops of family members do not drop in home network. So, it seems like the combination of my laptop and home wifi is not compatible. Laptop is connected to WIFI even though internet is dropped. Router is in my room and signal strength is very good. My network adapter is Intel(R) Wireless Ac 9462. If I reconnect again or right click and troubleshoot it fixes the issue. The troubleshooter says "The connection between your access point, router, or cable modem and the internet is broken -detected." "The default gateway is not available- fixed."

I have tried several solutions for permanent fix but in vain. I have tried the followings to fix the issue.

1. Unchecked "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power" in
   Power Management
2. WLAN Autoconfig windows service in Automatic mode.
3. Updated network adapter driver
4. Ran OS Network Trouble Shooter
5. Tried to reset network connections: Opened CMD or PowerShell and ran as an administrator and ran the commands below:
   netsh winsock reset

   netsh int ip reset

   netsh advfirewall reset

   ipconfig / flushdns

   ipconfig / release

   ipconfig / renew

Comment: Given what you have tried, try (a different) wireless USB adapter to see if a different adapter is better; and try updating the firmware on the wireless router.

Comment: You state, "Laptop is connected to WIFI even though internet is dropped." Could this have to do with DNS resolution or TCP setup? Compare network setup with another laptop.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am having similar issues with my Windows 10 laptop. If I stop WIFI and restart it will work, but only for an intermittent time.